# mock python instance method with argument or call original

Tags: python, class, methods, mocking, args

Given any class with an instance method `foo` that depends on an instance variable, e.g.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def foo(self, y: int):
        return self.x * y


def test_foo(mocker):
    a = A(1)
    y = -10
    assert a.foo(y) < 0
    mocker.patch.object(a, "foo", return_value=a.x * abs(y))
    assert a.foo(y) > 0
```

The question is how to mock `A(1).foo(y)` only for a test value of interest, e.g. `y < 0`, otherwise return the original call to `A(1).foo(y)`?  In this example above, the `y` value is already known, but for this question, please assume that it is unknown (deep in 3rd-party code, say) and it must be inspected from the call to `foo()`.  It seems like python mocks apply to all calls to `A(1).foo(y)` without any options to only apply a mock for specific values of `y` by inspecting the method call args.

For example, using pytest-mock, the test above works but it has no options to inspect the method call, check the args to the method call and only inject a mock when the args match some values of interest and otherwise call the original method.

Is the solution to create a subclass of `A` that can inspect args and return a mock value or call super, then use a mock to inject that subclass in place of `A`?  For example, building on the above example code:

```py
class B(A):

    def foo(self, y: int):
        if y < 0:
            return self.x * abs(y)
        else:
            super().foo(y)


def test_b_foo(mocker):
    a = A(1)
    y = -10
    assert a.foo(y) < 0
    mocker.patch.object(A, "foo", side_effect=B(a.x).foo)
    assert a.foo(y) > 0
```

This works OK, but it assumes that `A` is already initialized and it uses the instance `a` to initialize `B`.  How could the mock substitute calls to `A(i)` with calls to `B(i)` so that the test actually calls `B(i).foo(y)`?  What happens when the mocks for a specific argument to `A(i).foo(y)` for some specific `y` should apply to the `A.foo` method no matter how or when it is initialized?  I'm looking for something like the ruby mocks that apply a mock return value only when the patched object (method) is called with some specific arguments.  It seems like some kind of spy might be able to dynamically inject a return value when it detects a method call with specific arguments (to short-circuit the original method), but otherwise call the original method.  I guess it would be something like:

```py
m = mock.patch.object(A, "foo")
m.called_with(y < 0).return_value = mock_specific_to_args
# otherwise m.foo(10) calls the original method
```

Comment: Use the value of `y` to decide whether to mock `A.foo` at all, rather than using it to conditionally configure a mock.

Comment: @chepner - your comment still begs this question and, although the question example has a given `y`, the real use-case has to work with any `y`.

Comment: Your question doesn't show a case where you need to decide whether or not to mock the method before you have access to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with your `B.foo` idea, but it doesn't have to be a class and can just be a lambda that checks the logic (assuming you saved the original `A.foo`). I'm not totally clear on how all the `Mock` constructor args work, so I just use `patch()`'s `new` parameter, like this:

```py
orig_a_foo = A.foo
with patch.object(A, 'foo', new=lambda self, y: self.x * abs(y) if y < 0 else orig_a_foo(self, y)):
    assert a.foo(-10) == 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the value of `y` to decide whether to mock `A.foo` or not.

```
def test_foo(mocker):
    a = A(1)
    y = -10
    assert a.foo(y) < 0
    if y < 0:
        mocker.patch.object(a, "foo", return_value=a.x * abs(y))
    assert a.foo(y) > 0
```

Comment: I understand this answer and I appreciate the effort, but the examples are not exactly what I'm asking to solve.  I'm looking for a mock/spy pattern that can target arguments.  My examples are just illustrations of code that should be replaced by the mock/spy pattern(s), really.

Comment: I don't think you can. A name is either mocked or it isn't. The time to decide whether you want the real object or not isn't after you've already mocked the name.